# Particular color and shape of a subview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor

I want to show a subview like this (that appears when I try to forward a mail).
How to select this shaded color? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Do you want an UIActionsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is UIActionSheet and following is a code for that

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet;

 actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose Option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: @"Rispondi",@"Rispondi a tutti",@"inoltra",@"stampa",nil];
 actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
 [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```